# I can't move my character in python space invaders game while shooting (using Zelle graphics package)

Tags: python, graphics

I have to make a space invaders game for my intermediate python class using the Zelle graphics package. I have been having some issues with the projectile, it will run through the code, shoot the bullet, and continue to move the bullet, but while the bullet is moving, I can't move the character. I assume this is a pretty simple problem, but I'm not experienced enough with programing yet. Thanks.

```
from graphics import *
from time import *
game_over = False
win = GraphWin("skulls and bones", 500, 500)
skull = Image(Point(250, 450), "skull_2.gif")
skull.draw(win)
bullet = Circle(Point(250, 250), 10)
bullet.setFill("red")


def bone():
    value = 0
    key = win.getKey()
    if key == "x":
        bullet.draw(win)
    return bullet


def space_ship_move():
    key = win.getKey()
    if key == "a":
        skull.move(-10, 0)
    if key == "d":
        skull.move(10, 0)
    if key == "x":
        bone()
        for i in range(100):
            sleep(1)
            bone().move(0, -5)
    return key


while not game_over:
    space_ship_move()'''
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: First, `win.getKey()` blocks until the user presses a key. You don't want to do that - use `win.checkKey()`. Second, you need to decouple animation and input handling because you want your bullet to also move if there is no input. You can do this with the following structure:

```
def space_ship_move():       
    handle_input()        
    animate()        
    sleep(0.1)
```

`handle_input()` is mostly what you already had in there:

```
bullet = None
bulletAnimStep = -1

def bone():
    global bullet, bulletAnimStep

    if bullet is not None:
        bullet.undraw()
    bullet = Circle(Point(250, 250), 10)
    bullet.setFill("red")
    bullet.draw(win)
    bulletAnimStep = 0

def handle_input():
    key = win.checkKey()
    if key == "a":
        skull.move(-10, 0)
    if key == "d":
        skull.move(10, 0)
    if key == "x":
        bone()
```

I assumed `bone()` was supposed to be responsible for creating a new bullet. This is what the current function does. It also sets a `bulletAnimStep` to `0`, indicating that we are at the beginning of the bullet animation. Our `animate()` can use that information to decide when to stop the bullet animation. This is how it could look:

```
def animate():
    global bulletAnimStep

    #animate bullet
    if bulletAnimStep >= 0:
        bulletAnimStep += 1
        bullet.move(0, -5)
        if bulletAnimStep >= 100:
            #the bullet has gone far enough
            bullet.undraw()
            bulletAnimStep = -1
```